# Searchable disk benchmarks

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd, flash, benchmarking

I'm trying to find a web site that has a searchable database of hard drive, SSD, and flash drive benchmarks.  Ideally I could search by model number and get the following information:

Seq read max, Seq read min, Seq read avg;

Seq write max, Seq write min, Seq write avg;

Seek time max, Seq time avg

Max IOPS

I want actual benchmark data and not just model specs.

Answer (score 4):

I go to [AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/bench/SSD/65) to get benchmark information of solid-state drives.

For flash drives, I've used [UsbFlashSpeed.com](http://usbflashspeed.com/).

[PassMark](http://www.harddrivebenchmark.net/) is useful for hard drive benchmark information.

Comment: AnandTech provides some of the info I was looking for.  PassMark only gives rankings without any details.  Thanks for the first two.